# function compare 2 columns on 2 csv files and email difference

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, function, datatable

I have a function which compares 1 column on 2 csv files (the csv data are stored as tables) and returns a table if item is on both files. This table will be emailed:

CSV FILE ONE: shop.csv

| CarShop |
| --- |
| Toyota |
| Honda |
| Nissan |

CSV FILE Two: store.csv

| CarStore |
| --- |
| Toyota |
| Opel |

```
Function Getcarboth(CarShopDT As DataTable, CarStoreDT As DataTable)

    Dim emaildt As DataTable = New DataTable()

    Dim dc As New DataColumn("Carboth")
    emaildt.Columns.Add(dc)

    For Each dr As DataRow In CarStoreDT.Rows

        Dim carid As String = dr("CarStore")

        For Each dr2 As DataRow In CarShopDT.Rows

            If carid = dr2("CarShop") Then

                Dim drnew As DataRow
                drnew = emaildt.NewRow()
                drnew("Carboth") = carid
                emaildt.Rows.Add(drnew)


            End If

        Next

    Next

    If emaildt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        CType(FindControl("email_dg"), DataGrid).DataSource = emaildt
        CType(FindControl("email_dg"), DataGrid).DataBind()

        sendmail()

    End If


End Function
```

It compares the 2 tables and creates another table with differences for output to email.
Current new table generated is below - as Toyota is on both:

| Carboth |
| --- |
| Toyota |

I am looking to change the code (or maybe rewrite it using arrays? I am not sure) as I have added another column to the files and want to compare both a different way.

The new tables will be similar to below:

CSV FILE ONE: shop.csv

| CarShop | Model |
| --- | --- |
| Toyota | Hilux |
| Honda | Accord |
| Nissan | GTR |

CSV FILE Two: store.csv

| CarStore | Model |
| --- | --- |
| Toyota | Hilux |
| Honda | Accord |

I want to code to compare both columns on the files and create table with 2 columns that doesnt exist on the CarStore File.
The output table should be:

| CarDiff | Model |
| --- | --- |
| Nissan | GTR |

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, this is better done in a database with your source data in tables, and comparison done via SELECT query using the appropriate `join` variant[left outer, etc]. The results can be retrieved by your VB.NET code(since you have used above) and emailed in the format you prefer.